# TS-React: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-context

I want to use following API call `createWorkout({ workoutName, userId });`. When I hover on userId, I get the warning: `Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)`.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(workoutName);
        try {
            const response = await createWorkout({ workoutName, userId });
            console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

The reason for the problem is, I defined userId number or null in my ContextAPI.

```
interface IUserAuthenticationContext {
    userToken: string | null;
    setUserToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>;
    userId: number | null;
    setUserId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>;
    handleLogout: () => void;
}
```

The userId for the request is defined as number:

```
export interface CreateWorkoutRequest {
    userId: number;
    workoutName: string;
}
```

The reason is, when the createWorkout function is called, the userId cannot be null anymore.

Do you have any other solution than defining userId for the API as <number | null> ?

Defining userId in CreateWorkoutRequest solves the problem:

```
export interface CreateWorkoutRequest {
    userId: number | null;
    workoutName: string;
}
```

However I don't think it is a nice solution because at the time when the API is called the userId can not be null anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) operator.
This operator tells TypeScript that you are sure the value is not null or undefined at the point where you use it.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(workoutName);
        try {
            const response = await createWorkout({ workoutName, userId: userId! });
            console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
};
```